# When to Use Scala TreeMap?

Tags: scala

Given the following example of [TreeMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.0/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap):

```
scala> import scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap
import scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap

scala> val tm = TreeMap( ("foo" -> List(2,1) ) )
tm: scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap[String,List[Int]] = Map(foo -> List(2, 1))

scala> tm + ("bar" -> List(300, 4) )
res0: scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap[String,List[Int]] = Map(bar -> List(300, 4), foo -> List(2, 1))

scala> res0 + ("bippy" -> List(4) )
res1: scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap[String,List[Int]] = Map(bar -> List(300, 4), bippy -> List(4), foo -> List(2, 1))
```

It's not clear to me as to when it's advantageous to use a TreeMap over a [Map](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.0/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Map). When is it?

Comment: The question doesn't make any sense, since a `TreeMap` is a `Map`.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but a scala `Map` uses hashes in order to look-up keys? Whereas, as I observed with a TreeMap, it actually sorts the keys.

Comment: `scala.collection.immutable.Map` is a trait with unimplemented methods. You're talking about `scala.collection.immutable.HashMap`. The apply method of the companion object sometimes returns instances of that interpretation.

Answer (score 12):

`TreeMap` guarantees that the entries that are in the map are in a sorted order using keys, where as `Map` does not make any such guarantee.

So, if you want an ordering of keys in a map use `TreeMap` otherwise a normal Map will suffice. A place where I use TreeMap is generating tokens for [Twitter's API](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/creating-signatures) . To create a token, it is required that a string be created using url params which are sorted lexigraphically. I get the url params in a map,then put it in a TreeMap to get it sorted.

Going a little deep -

Scala uses [Hash Tries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_tree_(persistent_data_structure)) to create a HashMap(which is the default implementation of a Map) where the data structure is a Trie and the keys are hashed. Also, Scala optimizes the HashMap when the size is less than 5([source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.0/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/HashMap.scala)). It provides a constant look up and insertion cost in normal cases.

On the other hand, TreeMaps are constructed using [Red Black trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree). Red Black tree has a look up and insertion cost of O(ln n).

So, use Map when you don't want the keys to be sorted for better performance.

More details are in the collection [docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/concrete-immutable-collection-classes.html#hash_tries)

Comment: Sorting is not the only difference between a HashMap and a TreeMap. There are also important performance differences.